# What are some evolutionary bugs in the human genome that could be ironed out by a god that is essentially intelligent evolution?

Tags: biology, evolution, humans, gods

In my setting, humanity's gods are real and benevolent, but not omnipotent. They did not create the human species, but rather showed up early in its evolutionary history (equivalent of 300 kya in our timeline) and have helped guide/nurture the species ever since. This species is essentially identical to our own, on an Earth-equivalent planet.

The world is very low-magic, essentially the gods are the only magic that exists, and their ability to interact with humans (especially early on) is limited to acting as intelligent evolution. Any mutations that could feasibly develop naturally, they can make happen deliberately. So no magic powers or super strength. But the gods are highly intelligent/enlightened/insightful, so the changes they make can still be quite effective. It doesn't have to be something that has already evolved naturally, just something that conceivably could.

The angle I'm approaching this from is that the gods want to maximise humans' satisfaction without depriving them of agency. They really are good gods. And they don't want to create a master race in their own image, they genuinely just want to help. So the areas they focus on are:

- Resistance to disease/defects/cancer
- Reduced sexual dimorphism to even things out between males and females
- Some kind of low-tech/automatic biotechnology so that humans won't be dependent on advanced medical tech from the get-go.

For example, elephants have a gene type that helps prevent them from getting cancer, which was evolutionarily advantageous since they're so big and have so many cells. This wasn't evolutionarily advantageous enough for us to develop so we're stuck with cancer, but these gods want what's best for humanity so they 'bestow' it.

Other ideas include:

- Making pregnancy safer (better designed hips)
- Universal blood type that is more resilient to disease/infection
- The ability to transfer inoculations via transfusion
- Improved physical size/strength for females to reduce sexual dimorphism
- Vastly reduced rate of congenital defects
- Reduction in the pain/discomfort of menstruation (or replacement of the process altogether, i.e. with absorption instead of shedding
- Increased favouring of the mother in Mother-Fetus Competition
- Ability to produce new teeth/bone/cartilage/etc.removal/replacement of menstruation entirely

My big question is, are there any flaws/errors/downsides/consequences of these changes that I haven't considered? Are some difficult to justify from a purely physical/biological perspective? There's obviously an element of magic involved so it's all a bit speculative, but I want it to be at least somewhat grounded in biological reality.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to Worldbuilding! Please focus on just one question when asking a ..question. Also note that your second question is probably too broad to be asked here; it's asking for a rolling list, and anything goes, while what we need in advance are clear parameters by which you can separate good from bad answers.

Comment: The reason the [help/on-topic] discourages brainstorming is that it's often open-ended, hypothetical and leads to all answers having equal value, all of which are prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. Do you have a specific worldbuilding problem you need help resolving?

Comment: Ah sorry, I tried to keep it more question-focused but I see how I veered into discussion. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Not sure how the edit will go, but as is now: "Making pregnancy safer (better designed hips)" - how would this work? Evolution optimised for a number of things at the same time, *wider hips* might just hamper running from predators (or competing with males). What compromises are you prepared to make with these changes?

Comment: (1) Why would reducing the already greatly reduced sexual dimorphism be considered a good thing? In the immortal words of the well-known motivational poster, *Vive la difference!* (And it goes against making birth easier.) (2) Fixing cancer is an ultra-modern first-world problem. For 99.9% of history people died of something else before they became old enough to die of cancer. (3) The obvious easy fixes, aka "low-hanging fruit" in managerese, are eliminating our dependence on vitamins, essential fatty acids, and essential amino acids. There is no profound chemical reason why we need them.

Comment: @Escaped dental patient    I did some research into that and was quite surprised to find that wider hips aren't actually associated with slower speed/reduced athleticism. It's important to remember that evolution doesn't necessarily optimise things mechanically, it just goes with whatever happens to work out best. Since this evolution is intelligent, it can thread the needle so to speak, and come up with ideal solutions.

Comment: @AlexP   (1) One sex being physically weaker than the other is not, in the gods' opinion, considered a difference worth celebrating, let alone keeping. 

(2) Babies can get cancer too. The Gods (really me) are of the belief that a deity can't be considered good/altruistic if they allow babies to die of cancer when it could be prevented. 

(3) Is really interesting. Could you elaborate or recommend me any sources to check out?

Comment: (1) The opinion(s) of the gods are irrelevant. The question asks for modifications which maximize the satisfaction of humans, not of gods. And most people are more attracted to people of the opposite sex who actually look like the opposite sex. Few people are attracted to ambiguously androgynous figures. (And anyway, making births easier while making men look like women has obvious unfavorable effects.) (2) Yes, but the gods would like make a list of mods in order of priority. (3) Vitamins, essential amino acids and essential fatty acids are compounds that the body *could* make, but doesn't.

Comment: [Vitamins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin). [Essential aminoacids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_amino_acid). [Essential fatty acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_fatty_acid). We *must* get them from food, or we die, because the machinery which was supposed to make them got broken in the course of natural evolution and was never repaired. For example, most amino acids are interchangeable in food; that's why in general we are only interested in how much proteins we eat. But *some* of them cannot be synthesized by the human body, and we need them ready made or we die.

Comment: (1) I'm asking about what the gods would do in this scenario, so their opinions matter. And a woman doesn't need to be slender/small to be attractive to men. I also didn't say that men would look exactly like women and women exactly like men, just that sexual dimorphism would be reduced i.e. women are physically larger/stronger. Even so, plenty of people are attracted to androgynous appearances. 

(2) Yeah and babies not getting cancer is a high priority. 

Not a fan of the hostile tone and tone-deaf assumptions, but thank you for the pointers on vitamins/acids. You can stop replying now.

Comment: There is a series of Reddit threads that are on this very subject: [Here is one example](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/40htlg/human_v101_launches_what_are_the_patch_notes/) [And another](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/i13r2/human_patch_11/) [And another](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/qh08eq/humanbody_20_just_dropped_what_features_fixes_and/) A Google of some combination of 'Human Patch Notes' or 'Human 2.0 patch notes' - Whilst most of the good ones are written by people programming and a lot of them are meant to be mildly humorous - examples like the fact

Answer (score 1):

Just on aesthetic grounds, I would argue for inverting the retina. You could have the light sensing cells on the top, and the blood vessels and nerves on the underneath. You would not get a detached retina because it could be stuck down firmly.

These beings who want to re-engineer humans may not see things in terms of individual human creature comforts and survival. They may want to do things like this because it 'is ugly and needs fixing', even though our eyes work well enough.

Breathing and feeding through the same pipe is also a bad design.

Comment: That's an interesting one!

Comment: I should have been clearer on this context but these gods are not trying to take away human agency/identity and warp them into a different form that they think is superior, which is obviously a fine line to walk when editing genes. They are making (relatively) small changes to improve quality of life, both at the time (~300kya) and for the future, when humans have developed further.

Answer (score 0):

Make bodies able to replace damaged/lost parts to a much greater degree. That is, have a finger cut off? No problem, it'll grow back.

Comment: Even more important is to be able to grow new teeth.